# XPath iteration Exception: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"

Tags: javascript, exception, dom, xpath

Slightly changed snippet from Mozilla's [Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Within_an_HTML_Document) is throwing exception.

`[Exception... "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"  code: "11" nsresult: "0x8053000b (InvalidStateError)"  location: "debugger eval code Line: 6"]`

Code:

```
var headings = document.evaluate('//h2', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();

while (thisHeading) {
  thisHeading.textContent = '\n';
  thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
}
```

The difference from original piece of code is that I'm altering elements - not just reading them.

Why do I see the exception and how to alter elements in iteration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's common problem when starting with xpath and javascript and for everyone who is in rush and don't read whole [introduction/documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript), so it should be on SO.

---

`headings.resultType` is `4` an `UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE`

> This is the default return type when the result of the XPath expression is a node set.

You have to know which `resultType` it is, because:

> XPathResult object allows node-sets to be returned in 3 principal different types:
>
> - Iterators
> - Snapshots
> - First Nodes

And the most important information is: **you cannot change DOM when node-set is one of the`*_ITERATOR_TYPE`**.

> ..if the document is mutated (the document tree is modified) between iterations that will invalidate the iteration and the invalidIteratorState property of XPathResult is set to true, and a NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_STATE_ERR exception is thrown.

So if you want to alter some elements you have to specifically ask for one of the Snapshots `resultType`. You have two options:

- UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE
- ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE

In your case this is what you want:

```
var headings = document.evaluate('//h2', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );

for ( var i=0 ; i < headings.snapshotLength; i++ ) {
   headings.snapshotItem(i).textContent = '\n';
}
```

And be aware of what you are changing:

> Snapshots do not change with document mutations, so unlike the iterators the snapshot does not become invalid, but it may not correspond to the current document, for example the nodes may have been moved, it might contain nodes that no longer exist, or new nodes could have been added.