# XPath error The document has mutated since the result was returned

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I'm trying to use xpath on a page but am getting the error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'iterateNext' on 'XPathResult': The document has mutated since the result was returned.`

```
xpath = document.evalutate('//a', document)
xpath.iterateNext()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath iteration Exception: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664219/xpath-iteration-exception-an-attempt-was-made-to-use-an-object-that-is-not-or)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that the page is mutated between the time the XPathResult object is generated and the time when you access an object in it.

Instead use snapshots

```
xpath = document.evaluate('//td/a', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
xpath.snapshotItem(0)
xpath.snapshotItem(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your propose is read only, it's possible to clone the context node:

```
xpath = document.evaluate('//a', document.cloneNode(true))
xpath.iterateNext()
```